# Trouble installing `wmctrl`

Tags: macos, installation, unix, osx-mountain-lion, wmctrl

It seems that wmctrl is not installed on my system (Mac OS 10.8), but when I try to install it by cloning a [git repo](https://github.com/dancor/wmctrl) and following the instructions (`./configure`, `make`, `make install`), running `make` results in a bunch of errors, the first few of which look like this:

```
main.c:33:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
main.c:34:23: error: X11/Xatom.h: No such file or directory
main.c:35:28: error: X11/cursorfont.h: No such file or directory
main.c:36:29: error: X11/Xmu/WinUtil.h: No such file or directory
```

Does the `wmctrl` directory need to be somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

run `brew install homebrew/homebrew-core/wmctrl`

**old answer**

I got it using homebrew `brew install homebrew/x11/wmctrl` from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11

Comment: Looks like it is `brew install homebrew/homebrew-core/wmctrl` now